# Counter-examples in representations of associative algebra

Tags: representation-theory, examples-counterexamples, characters

Here are something well-known.

$V \cong W \Rightarrow  \chi_V=\chi_W$ holds for finite representations of arbitrary associative algebra.

But $ \chi_V=\chi_W \Rightarrow V \cong W $ is true only for finite representations of finite group.

Could anyone give a counter-example that two nonisomorphic finite representations of an associative algebra have the same character ?

Comment: Let $B$ be the upper triangular matrices in $GL(2,k)$ for $k$ a field. Then the non-isomorphic representations sending $(a,b;0,d)$ to $(a,b;0,d)$ and $(a,0;0,d)$ have the same trace. Now let the associative algebra be the group algebra.

Comment: An even simpler example where the field has positive characteristic: Let your algebra be $k=\mathbb{F}_2$ and $V=0$, $W=k^2$. Then $\chi_V=\chi_W=0$, but clearly $V\not\cong W$.

Comment: 2 is true for completely reducibility representations in characteristic 0.

Comment: It will fail for any non competely reducible representation.

Comment: You may read about Tannakian categories, which are equivalent to the category of representations of group schemes. The category of finite dimensional representations of a group scheme determines it.